# Python - dropping special unix characters

Tags: python, encoding, special-characters

When viewing a log file on my (solaris) machine, I can see it is formatted as "^A1=hello^A2=goodbye^A3=salut". I am looking to be able to use a string.split("^A") so I can break the line into parts and use the key value pairs.

However when I loop through this same file in python 2.6.4, It is loaded as "1=hello2=goodbye3=salut" and I cannot split it.

When I run a file command on this I get
file Tom.log
Tom.log:     c program text

I have tried importing codecs (as below) and selecting 'UTF-8', but no joy. Any help is appreciated.

import codecs
f = codecs.open('Tom.log', 'r', 'UTF-8')
for line in f:
    print(line)

Comment: Those are Control-A characters, ASCII value 1.  You could write them as `"\x01"` in a Python string literal (to replace them with something more useful, perhaps).

Comment: thank you Jason, that has worked. Appreciate the help.